# How to download a csv file from local folder in .net windows form application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms

i need a help regarding download a sample file from local machine .could anyone please help me .

i tried below code ,

```
 string value = " ~/DE_V04/DE_V04/WindowsFormsApp1/Files/sample.csv";
 WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
 Uri url = new Uri(value);
 webClient.DownloadFileAsync(url, "~/sample.csv");
```

Comment: Well, can you describe what happens when you run that code? Do you listen to the [DownloadFileCompleted](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadfilecompleted?view=netframework-4.7.2) event?

Comment: nothing is happening, If I get any exceptions, I will check.

Comment: you have mix up - winforms or asp.net ?

Comment: I am using winforms

Answer (score 2):

It seems as you just want to copy a file from one directory (which you have access to) to another directory (which you also have access to)? If so, there is no need for web requests. You could simply use

```
File.Copy(string sourceFileName, string destFileName)
```

See [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.copy?view=netframework-4.7.2).